# Custom LWC Flow Screen Component - reportValidity not highlighting field in red

Tags: lightning-web-components, visual-workflow, flow-screen-component, lightning-textarea

I have a really simple FSC (simplified for this question).  It just contains a `lightning-textarea`.

I'm trying to get the textarea to be outlined in red when the user clicks Next on a Flow screen and the validation fails.

The behavior I'm currently seeing is the validity is enforced (the user can't progress to next screen without providing a value), but the textarea doesn't get the red outline.

I have confirmed the flow is calling my validate method, which in turn calls reportValidity on the textarea.

Is there a way to get the textarea to have the red border when the user clicks Next and it fails validation?

[image]

LWC html

```
<template>
    <lightning-textarea
        label={label}
        required={required}
        value={value}
        class="my-text-area"
        onchange={handleChange}>
    </lightning-textarea>
</template>
```

LWC js

```
export default class CclLongTextArea extends LightningElement {
    @api value = '';

    // input parameters
    @api label = '';
    @api required = false;

    handleChange(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        // eslint-disable-next-line @lwc/lwc/no-api-reassignments
        this.value = event.detail.value?.trim();

        this.template.querySelector('.my-text-area').reportValidity();

        // tell the flow
        this.dispatchEvents();
    }

    dispatchEvents() {

        this.dispatchEvent(new FlowAttributeChangeEvent('value', this.value));

    }

    @api
    validate() {

        const isValid = this.template.querySelector('.my-text-area').reportValidity();

        if( isValid ) {
            return { isValid: true };
        }

        return {
            isValid: false,
            errorMessage: ''
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are validating on the wrong class'.cts-text-area' but the text-area has '.my-text-area' as the class.

You can also use **setCustomValididty** method or **message-when-value-missing** attribute of the text area.

```
        <lightning-textarea
        message-when-value-missing='Please enter the value'
        class='my-text-area' required></lightning-textarea>
```

```
this.template.querySelector('.my-text-area').setCustomValidity('Complete this field');
```

Comment: This doesn't make the red highlight appear when the user clicks the Next button. It just changes the error message to a custom message when the user blurs the textarea without entering any text

Comment: you can try logging the return value of const validtity = this.template.querySelector('.my-text-area').reportValidity();. It's working fine for me.

Comment: can you share the code how are you using the validate method?

Comment: check the updated answer

Comment: Sorry, I copied the code incorrectly.  The code does have 'my-text-area'. I've updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is component is getting reinitialized again when you click next in flow screen and return false from validate method in lwc.

You can handle the situation by using **sessionStorage**. I am storing a variable in session named showError with value true and false based on **reportValidity()** of **textarea** input.

```
    @api
    validate() {
        console.log('validate called');
        const isValid = this.template.querySelector('lightning-textarea').reportValidity();
        if (isValid) {
            sessionStorage.setItem("showError", false);
            return { isValid: true };
        }
        sessionStorage.setItem("showError", true);
        return {
            isValid: false,
            errorMessage: ''
        }
    }
```

Also, changed the textarea input handler as:-

```
 handletextChange(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        // eslint-disable-next-line @lwc/lwc/no-api-reassignments
        this.value = event.detail.value?.trim();
        const isValid = this.template.querySelector('lightning-textarea').reportValidity();
        if (isValid) {
            sessionStorage.setItem("showError", false);
        } else {
            sessionStorage.setItem("showError", true);
        }
        // tell the flow
        this.dispatchEvents();
    }
```

and then in renderedCallback, based on session variable, report the validity.

```
renderedCallback() {
        if (sessionStorage.getItem("showError") && this.template.querySelector('lightning-textarea') && !this.value) {
            console.log('showing error');
            this.template.querySelector('lightning-textarea').reportValidity();
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This has given me the key understanding of the problem (the reinitialization of the LWC) but I don't think this approach will work if there's more than one LWC on the flow screen, because the session storage doesn't tell us which LWC should or shouldn't show the error.

Comment: You can store a json with data-id for elements and their respective showError value in the session storage. It can help you in telling which component should show the error.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you mean we'd have to pass in a unqiue identifier to the LWC, and use this in the session storage to uniquely identify the LWC?

Comment: Yes, I mean the same.